# Ethernet speed / scp

Tags: ssh, ethernet, performance

I'm just copying a bunch of files from a RaspPi 3 to my laptop using `scp` over an Ethernet connection. The speed is abysmal, around 0.5 to 0.6 MB/sec. Is this normal? I read somewhere that with 10/100 Ethernet you should get something like 12 MB/sec. Is the micro-SD card the bottle-neck here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question/answer over at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112287/copy-files-without-encryption-ssh-in-local-network). Basically the bottle-neck is the encryption, and the two solutions are either to use a 'cheap' cipher or a different program for copying such as `rcp`.

Comment: I'd still say it is odd.  I get transfer times of 3-6 MB/s over ethernet using `scp` or `sshfs` (I much prefer the latter though, which is sftp based), no special cipher.   The fastest I've seen a pi sustain sans encryption is ~10 MB/s.

Comment: Not completely. The fault is the protocol itself. SCP is not made for performance.

Comment: @goldilocks 10 MB/s is about as fast as the Raspberry network port can transport data.  These days ssh on a modern x64 CPU can utilize hardware encryption making it easy to saturate a gigabit connection.  The Raspberry does not have this unfortunately.  Run top in a parallel session to see if the cpu is fully used by ssh - if yes, it is the encryption.

Answer (score 4):

SCP is based on SSH. And SSH [itself has some overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#/media/File:Ssh_binary_packet_alt.svg):
[image: wiki]

SCP is really naive protocol with really naive algorithm for transferring a few of small files. It has a lot of synchronization (RTT - Round Trip Time) and small buffers (basically 2048 B -- [source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L763)).

If you want performance, use `sftp`.
SFTP is more advanced and more ready for transferring files. It has bigger buffers which decreases need for synchronization and increases speed. I guess you would achieve similar results with `rsync`, which is probably the most appropriate tool to transfer data. [Buffer has by default 32 768 B](http://rc.quest.com/man.php?id=sftp%281%29) = 32 kB, but it is configured on command-line using `-B` switch.

<sup>Original answer on [Unix.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769366/what-makes-throughput-of-the-sftp-and-scp-protocols-different)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Argh, don't use ssh for LAN data transfer. In a shell, cd to the directory that contains your files, and invoke `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 31415` - then mirror that from your laptop at http://pi_ip:31415 .

Didn't notice you were just copying on LAN. Across internet, you should use compression, ssh uses gzip/zlib, it doesn't lag the processor noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a better solution is to use `rsync`.

This is assuming your laptop supports it (all Linux and OS X do), and it suits your problem. `rsync`, as its name implies is good at keeping directories in synch, and only copies needed changes.

Comment: Most informal uses of `rsync` are done over `ssh` so would still incur the overheads of using `ssh`. You can tweak the `ssh` used by `rsync` with the latter's `-e` command-line option (the exception is when `rsync` uses its own protocol to connect directly to a remote *rsync server daemon* without using `ssh` but that requires the remote end to have been configured with a server daemon).

Answer (score 0):

The *theoretical maximum* for the ethernet interface is 12.5MiB/s (100Mib / 8 bits) - that's *Megabytes per second*. However, the Pi is somewhat bound by the fact that the network goes through the USB interface. As other answers suggest, you can probably get more improvements by not using `ssh` but, if you need to use it, then you can apply some command-line arguments to make it a bit faster:

#### 1. Don't compress

There's no point in compressing across the LAN, but old habits die hard and many people do it without thinking. Remove the compression and the performance is a more reasonable 1.86MiB/s. But that can be improved upon.

#### 2. Use a weak cipher

You can't disable encryption with ssh but you can minimise its impact by using a weak cipher. Try the command with `-c arcfour,blowfish-cbc`.

You can read my [original post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=102615&p=710352&hilit=+ssh#p710352) on the Raspberry Pi Forum.

Answer (score 0):

Either use an FTP service which only allows access by an unprivileged user  ( certainly not sudo's NOPASSWD ) or netcat. On the receiving end do: `nc -v -l 9999 | tar -xvf - -C /tmp`, and on the sending side do `tar -cvf - dir1 file1 dir2 file2 etc | nc -v yourPiIPHere 9999`. My old pi1b+ would use 100% cpu with scp. If you must, super-compress the archive with 'dd if=archive.tar bs=512M | xz  -e9vfc > archive.tar.xz' and scp that over. Use `tar -Jxvf archive.tar.xz` to unpack it.

Comment: This runs at 2.7 mb/sec from my OSX to Rasperry Pi 3

Comment: The ethernet chip is shared with other devices on the USB bus. Could be your problem.